# Multiple query in prometheus throwing No datapoints found error

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

Facing error while running two query at once.

Query1:

```
sum by(container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name) (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_io_kubernetes_container_name=~"demo-api"}[1m]))
```

O/P:

```
{container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name="demo-api-demo-api-7c8d7c75d-sfrsg"}    0.15590349995998623
{container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name="demo-api-demo-api-7c8d7c75d-nnxqz"}    0.22167272938000676
{container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name="demo-api-demo-api-7c8d7c75d-zbcdk"}    0.14510123627695987
```

Ouery2:

```
avg(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="demo-api"})
```

O/P:

```
Element     Value
{}  1
```

Final query(q1/q2):

```
(sum by(container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name) (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_io_kubernetes_container_name=~"demo-api"}[1m])))
/(avg(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="demo-api"}))
```

**No datapoints found.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Prometheus documentation here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) describes how vector matching works.
For your operation to succeed, you need to ignore the `container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name` label during the division:

```
(sum by(container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name) (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_io_kubernetes_container_name=~"demo-api"}[1m])))
/
ignoring(container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name) group_left 
avg(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="demo-api"})
```

Comment: Work well, just had to removed bracket around avg, here is the updated one `(sum by(container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name) (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_io_kubernetes_container_name=~"template-api"}[1m])))/ignoring(container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name) group_left 
avg(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores{container="template-api"})`